# Angular2 app works in Chrome and IE, but not Firefox or Safari

Tags: firefox, safari, angular

App works fine in Chrome and IE(11), but not in Firefox (42.0) or Safari (5.1.7).

**FIREFOX**:

mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create es6-shim.js:1338:11

Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode. angular2.dev.js:351:5

EXCEPTION: Error: Expected int32 as second argument angular2.dev.js:23524

```js
BrowserDomAdapter</BrowserDomAdapter.prototype.logError() angular2.dev.js:23514
BrowserDomAdapter</BrowserDomAdapter.prototype.logGroup() angular2.dev.js:23525
ExceptionHandler</ExceptionHandler.prototype.call() angular2.dev.js:1145
PlatformRef_</PlatformRef_.prototype._initApp/</<() angular2.dev.js:14801
NgZone</NgZone.prototype._notifyOnError() angular2.dev.js:5796
NgZone</NgZone.prototype._createInnerZone/errorHandling<.onError() angular2.dev.js:5700
run() angular2-polyfills.js:141

map@http://localhost:53861/lib/es6-shim/es6-shim.js:1113:14
TemplateParseVisitor</TemplateParseVisitor.prototype._createDirectiveAsts@http://localhost:53861/lib/anguar2/angular2.dev.js:24301:27
TemplateParseVisitor</TemplateParseVisitor.prototype.visitElement@http://localhost:53861/lib/anguar2/angular2.dev.js:24154:24
HtmlElementAst</HtmlElementAst.prototype.visit@http://localhost:53861/lib/anguar2/angular2.dev.js:20216:14
htmlVisitAll/<@http://localhost:53861/lib/anguar2/angular2.dev.js:20227:23
forEach@http://localhost:53861/lib/es6-shim/es6-shim.js:1107:14
htmlVisitAll@http://localhost:53861/lib/anguar2/angular2.dev.js:20226:5
TemplateParser</TemplateParser.prototype.parse@http://localhost:53861/lib/anguar2/angular2.dev.js:24038:20
TemplateCompiler</TemplateCompiler.prototype._compileComponentRuntime/done<@http://localhost:53861/lib/anguar2/angular2.dev.js:24669:32
run@http://localhost:53861/lib/anguar2/angular2-polyfills.js:138:14
NgZone</NgZone.prototype._createInnerZone/<.$run/<@[…]
```

**SAFARI**:

```js
EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of BrowserDetails! (Token Promise<ComponentRef> -> DynamicComponentLoader -> Compiler -> RuntimeCompiler -> ProtoViewFactory -> Renderer -> DomRenderer -> AnimationBuilder -> BrowserDetails).
angular2.dev.js:23514ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'window.requestAnimationFrame(callback)')
```

```js
Potentially unhandled rejection [2] Error: EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of BrowserDetails! (Token Promise<ComponentRef> -> DynamicComponentLoader -> Compiler -> RuntimeCompiler -> ProtoViewFactory -> Renderer -> DomRenderer -> AnimationBuilder -> BrowserDetails).
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'window.requestAnimationFrame(callback)')
 Error loading http://localhost:53861/app/bootDesktop.js
```

---

Any ideas as to what is wrong greatly appreciated.  It looks like it has something to do with "BrowserDomAdapter".

Comment: The issue with firefox was [fixed](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim/issues/347) in 0.34.0 (es6-shim). And for safari there's a [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671) for requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: It seems i am referencing es6-shim: v0.33.13.  Will upgrade, and add the polyfill.  Many thx for the tip!

Comment: @EricMartinez  worked like a charm!

Comment: Good! I'm glad it worked :D!

Answer (score 1):

issue resolved by upgrade the es6-shim.