# For my Angular 2 app in Safari my app doesn't show, just has a blue screen

Tags: angularjs, safari, angular

For my Angular 2 app in Safari my app doesn't show, just has a blue screen

My app works fine in firefox, chrome and ie.

I get this error in the console for the new safari script fix for es6:

Refused to execute script from 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/paulirish/1579671/raw/682e5c880c92b445650c4880a6bf9f3897ec1c5b/rAF.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

This is my es6 script version:

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.34.2/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
```

**This is the error I see in the console for Safari?**

[image]

Could it be a es6 javascript error?

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701144/angular2-app-works-in-chrome-and-ie-but-not-firefox-or-safari

Comment: mine works fine in firefox though

Comment: The first comment says it's fixed for Firefox and there is a shim for Safari.

Comment: I had a look at that link but couldnt find the correct es6-shim for safari or js script for safari that i need to add?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems you need to add this polyfill https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671
See also [Angular2 app works in Chrome and IE, but not Firefox or Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701144/angular2-app-works-in-chrome-and-ie-but-not-firefox-or-safari)

Comment: this one:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/paulirish/1579671/raw/682e5c880c92b445650c4880a6bf9f3897ec1c5b/rAF.js