# Internet Explorer and Edge are missing "es6-shim.map" by giving a 404 NotFound

Tags: internet-explorer, angular

I am developing an Angular2-Application with SignalR. I load the js-Files you need to get IE and Edge going like this:

```
<script src="js/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/system-polyfills.js"></script>
```

Which google also says in their examples to load these because IE requires them. However, when I start my application it works in IE so far, but I get the message:

> HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the
>   requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). (XHR): GET -
>   http://localhost:5000/js/es6-shim.map

in the console which makes SignalR really really slow - almost not working. Why does IE look for a *.map-file? Did I forgot to include something?

Chrome and Firefox are working fine. But I get the message

> mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create

in Firefox. This would explain a bit, but I am not modifying any prototype anywhere.

Comment: You get that message when you open the console.right?

Comment: A workaround could be adding the [es6-shim.map](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paulmillr/es6-shim/master/es6-shim.map) to your `js/` folder.

Comment: Removal of system-polyfills.js does not help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at [this](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim/blob/master/es6-shim.min.js) you will see on the last line:

```
 //# sourceMappingURL=es6-shim.map
```

This will trigger the search for the map file. [Introduction to JavaScript Source Maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps) explains in detail that a source map holds information about the original files. The [debugger](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/f12-devtools-guide/deb) help Edge F12 tool help page, section source maps, explains why you get an error. So you have several options:

- Remove the last line from the minified file.
- Deploy also the map file, included in the NPM package.
- Ignore the error in Edge F12 tools or select an alternative .map location ("Choose source map") option explained in the help file.

Regarding the exception message: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701144/angular2-app-works-in-chrome-and-ie-but-not-firefox-or-safari) question.