# Error Running Angular 2 Cli in Safari

Tags: angular, safari

I get the following error running my Angular 2 app in Safari:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (index.js.map, line 0)
```

I don't have this issue with Chrome. Does anyone know the reason?

I am using:
@angular/common: 2.2.3,
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.22-1
Safari Version 9.1 (11601.5.17.1)

Maint.ts

```
import './polyfills.ts';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "todo1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.3",
    "angular2-color-picker": "^1.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "tslint": "^4.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.22-1",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you install the polyfills? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701144/angular2-app-works-in-chrome-and-ie-but-not-firefox-or-safari

Comment: maybe it is a too much old version of safari.. (now it is 10.*) ..could it be? .are you transpiling your app in es5 or 6?

Comment: what are the **errors** in your cosole and add the code without which nothing can be done.

Comment: Looking at my main.ts looks like I did install pollyfill but no longer using it. If remove the import I get the following error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Reflect.getMetadata'). How would I remove it? Also I've updated my question with my main.ts and package.json. The error given is the console error.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue . Please help